# Android one install

Tags: custom-roms, android-one

After wondering for a lot of years I recently got a fair idea on what is the difference between stock android, android one and many other custom rom. Now I want to play around with it and was thinking to install Grapheneos. I have a Motorola One Power. Now the question is: say I mess up while installing Grapheneos or say I did install it successfully and decide to switch back to Android One, how do I do it? I tried searching online but couldn't find anything. All I got was to install android one "experience" which is basically just installing a launcher.

One more thing, since Android updates are directly given by Google for all the phones, why do I have to download the OS for a phone from it's manifactrer's website instead of downloading it from the android website?
(someone posted a duckduckgo search for what I asked which is kind of what I was looking for, I found a Motorola page for the custom ROM for my device.)

Also, do you guys have any tips before I go on installing? By the way, I am a Linux user if that concerns in any to the question.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Motorola+One+Power+stock+ROM%2C+factory+firmware

Comment: isn't stock ROM customized stock android, so this is basically, might not be, what my phone came pre-installed with? am I right? do I make sense?

Comment: You are wrong the OS and every update are always provided by the device manufacturer. Google only provides the Android system to the manufacturers and certifies in the end that the device is Android compliant.

Comment: oh, didn't know that